# Mysql user definied function as Computed stored column

Tags: mysql

I'd like to add a computed spatial column that has the value of a function i wrote in MySQL 5.7.11

> ALTER TABLE `blocks` CHANGE `point_coord` `point_coord` POINT AS
>   (**tile2point(`x`,`y`,20)**) STORED;

And I get an error:

> **Expression of generated column 'point_coord' contains a disallowed function.**

tile2point is user definied that returns with a POINT type.

When I use the basic point() it's **working**

> ALTER TABLE `blocks` CHANGE `point_coord` `point_coord` POINT AS
>   (**POINT**(`x`,`y`)) STORED;

But there are some other things i needed to do, thats why i made my function.

Also this is working as expected:

> Select *,tile2point(`x`,`y`,20) as point_coord from blocks

I just want to store it, not to compute it on every query.

What's need to be done to store the functions return values in a column?

Comment: `Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted.`. See [13.1.18 CREATE TABLE Syntax :: CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Comment: @wchiquito So is the only way to do what he's trying to accomplish with triggers?

Comment: @BrianLeishman: It doesn't seem to be an option, due to the following restriction: `Triggers cannot use NEW.col_name or use OLD.col_name to refer to generated columns.`. See [14.1.18.7 CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

Comment: @wchiquito Yeah I get that, I was just saying that if he wanted to denormalize the column and to get the the same end result, that triggers could help replace the lack of support for custom functions